# outlook api php add event

Tags: api, outlook

I tried to add an event using  in php :this form look like :

```
<form class="form"  method="POST">  
    date  : <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="AAAA-MM-JJ" />
    start : <input type="text" name="startTime" />
    end   : <input type="text" name="endTime" />
    Sujet : <input type="text" name="subject" />
    Description : <input type="text" name="description" />      
    <button type="submit" name="add"> Ajouter évenement </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cSession = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://myremotesite.com/admin/profit");
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$result = curl_exec($cSession);
echo $result;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.